# GRUB scrolls off top of screen

Tags: grub2, pager

I'm entering commands at the GRUB2 prompt on Debian 9.  If I run e.g. `help` or `lsmod`, there is more than one screens-worth of output, and it just scrolls off the top so I can only read the last screen.  Since this isn't a unix shell I can't use `| more`.  How are you supposed to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the output goes off-screen, you'll need to run "set pager=1" first.

https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2013/11/msg00464.html